# Distinct values across XSLT nodesets

Tags: xslt, xpath, node-set

Once again about the distinct nodes (basing on attribute values) in node set.
Imagine u have the following structure:

```
<struct>
  <a>
    <x id="1">a_1</x>
    <x id="2">a_2</x>
    <x id="3">a_3</x>
  </a>
  <b inherits="a">
    <x id="2">b_2</x>
  </b>
</struct>
```

`<struct/>` may contain multiple elements like `<b/>` which inherit the same `<a/>`. At the same time multiple elements like `<a/>` are allowed. Order of `<a/>`s and `<b/>`s is arbitrary. Inheritance is single-level deep.

**Question**: How to create a *single* XPath that selects the following nodeset for a given `<b/>`:

```
<x id="1">a_1</x>
<x id="2">b_2</x>
<x id="3">a_3</x>
```

Please note the `b_2` value on the second line.

Any solutions to this?

**Update:**

The resuting XPath should have the following form: `b[(magic_xpath)[@id=2]='b_2']`, where `magic_xpath` selects distinct `<x/>`s from `<a/>`s and `<b/>`s.

The real life `<struct/>` can look like this:

```
<struct>
  <a>
    <x id="1">a_1</x>
    <x id="2">a_2</x>
    <x id="3">a_3</x>
  </a>
  <b inherits="a">
    <x id="2">I don't match resulting XPath</x>
  </b>
  <b inherits="a">
    <x id="2">b_2</x>
  </b>
</struct>
```

Comment: The meaning of the update isn't clear. What should be the result and why you need "distinct `<x/>`s when all `x` elements in your update already have distinct values?. Please update the update to make it clear and unambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

**Use**:

```
  $vB/x
 |
  /*/*[name() = $vB/@inherits]
                /x[not(@id = $vB/x/@id)]
```

where `$vB` is defined to be the `b` element.

This selects the union of all `b/x` elements and all `x` children (with `id` attribute that isn't equal to any `b/x/@id` attribute) of `struct/*` elements (children of `struct`) whose name is the value of `b/@inherits`.

Or, as requested by the OP in a comment -- without variables:

```
  /*/b/x
 |
  /*/*[name() = /*/b/@inherits]
                /x[not(@id = /*/b/x/@id)]
```

**Complete XSLT-based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:copy-of select=
     "/*/b/x
     |
      /*/*[name() = /*/b/@inherits]
                    /x[not(@id = /*/b/x/@id)]

   "/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the provided (corrected to be well-formed) XML document**:

```
<struct>
    <a>
        <x id="1">a_1</x>
        <x id="2">a_2</x>
        <x id="3">a_3</x>
    </a>
    <b inherits="a">
        <x id="2">b_2</x>
    </b>
</struct>
```

**the single XPath expression is evaluated and the selected nodes are output**:

```
<x id="1">a_1</x>
<x id="3">a_3</x>
<x id="2">b_2</x>
```

Comment: Thank u for such a quick answer! But, is it possible to do the same thing _without_ declaring a variable?

Comment: Yes, just substitute `$vB` with `/*/b`

Comment: @Savva Mikhalevski: I edited the answer with an XPath expression that doesn't reference any variables.

Comment: Unfortunately, the description of problem I gave in not complete. Please see my update.